# BCP queryout command creates text file but hangs when executed within a job step in a transaction

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, jobs, bcp

Okay, I've been battling with this problem for almost a week now and I cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is.

Problem: BCP utility creates txt file but nothing happens after. The file just sits there and is blank. BCP pretty much hangs. I have to End Process to get stop it. The BCP command is inside a stored procedure that is inside a transaction that is inside a job step. If I take the sproc itself and run it in management studio, the file is created without a problem. If I create a SQL job and put JUST the sproc that runs the BCP command, it ALSO works.

This is the job step:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

EXEC dbo.DataManipulation1
EXEC dbo.DataManipulation2
EXEC dbo.DataManipulation3
EXEC dbo.DataManipulation4
EXEC dbo.DataManipulation5

EXEC dbo.spCreateFiles 0

EXEC dbo.spSendEmail 'PASS'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

EXEC dbo.spGetDatabaseErrorInfo
EXEC dbo.spCreateFiles 1
EXEC dbo.spSendEmail 'FAIL'
END CATCH
```

Here's the spCreateFiles sproc. The high level overview: Sproc generate system folders then does a queryout to a txt file. That's it. If the parameter being passed to the sproc is 0, it'll generate files based on the execution of a sproc, if the parameter is NOT 0, then it'll generate blank files. It's a total of 4 files. The username and password for the BCP command is removed for obvious reasons. From some of my reading online, it might be because something is locking up the file... maybe the sproc or the SQL job or even the transation and then when the BCP utility tries to use it, nothing happens.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateFiles] @errorCode BIT
AS 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            DECLARE @year CHAR(4)
            DECLARE @month CHAR(2)
            DECLARE @day CHAR(2)

            DECLARE @rootDir VARCHAR(200)
            DECLARE @yearDir VARCHAR(200)
            DECLARE @monthDir VARCHAR(200)
            DECLARE @dayDir VARCHAR(200)
            DECLARE @dirsTable TABLE (directory VARCHAR(200))

            DECLARE @baseFileName VARCHAR(8)
            DECLARE @detailFile VARCHAR(500)
            DECLARE @detailNydFile VARCHAR(500)
            DECLARE @summaryFile VARCHAR(500)
            DECLARE @summaryNydFile VARCHAR(500)

            DECLARE @cmdQueryout VARCHAR(2000)

            SET @rootDir = 'C:\Test\'
            SET @year = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
            SET @month = RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())), 2)
            SET @day = RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())), 2)
            SET @yearDir = @rootDir + @year + '\'
            SET @monthDir = @rootDir + @year + '\' + @year + @month + '\'
            SET @dayDir = @rootDir + @year + '\' + @year + @month + '\' + @year + @month + @day + '\'
            SET @baseFileName = @year + @month + @day

            PRINT @rootDir

            PRINT @year
            PRINT @month
            PRINT @day

            PRINT @yearDir
            PRINT @monthDir
            PRINT @dayDir

            PRINT @baseFileName

            INSERT  INTO @dirsTable
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @rootDir

            IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  directory
                            FROM    @dirsTable
                            WHERE   directory = @year ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @yearDir

            DELETE  FROM @dirsTable    

            INSERT  INTO @dirsTable
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @yearDir

            IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  directory
                            FROM    @dirsTable
                            WHERE   directory = @month ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @monthDir
            DELETE  FROM @dirsTable   

            INSERT  INTO @dirsTable
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @monthDir

            IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  directory
                            FROM    @dirsTable
                            WHERE   directory = @day ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @dayDir
            DELETE  FROM @dirsTable 

            SET @detailFile = @dayDir + @baseFileName + ' Detail.txt'
            SET @detailNydFile = @dayDir + @baseFileName + ' Detail_NYD.txt' 
            SET @summaryFile = @dayDir + @baseFileName + ' Summary.txt'
            SET @summaryNydFile = @dayDir + @baseFileName + ' Summary_NYD.txt'

            PRINT @detailFile
            PRINT @detailNydFile
            PRINT @summaryFile
            PRINT @summaryNydFile

            IF @errorCode = 0 
                BEGIN     
                    PRINT 'Error Code: ' + CAST(@errorCode AS CHAR(1))  
                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "EXEC DB_NAME.dbo.spGetDetailRecords" queryout "' + @detailFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'
                    PRINT @cmdQueryout

                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout  

                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "EXEC DB_NAME.dbo.spGetDetailNYDRecords" queryout "' + @detailNydFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'
                    PRINT @cmdQueryout  

                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout    

                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "EXEC DB_NAME.dbo.spGetSummaryRecords" queryout "' + @summaryFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'
                    PRINT @cmdQueryout

                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout        

                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "EXEC DB_NAME.dbo.spGetSummaryNYDRecords" queryout "' + @summaryNydFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'
                    PRINT @cmdQueryout

                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout 
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "SELECT NULL" queryout "' + @detailFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'
                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout  

                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "SELECT NULL" queryout "' + @detailNydFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'                 
                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout    

                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "SELECT NULL" queryout "' + @summaryFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'
                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout        

                    SET @cmdQueryout = 'bcp "SELECT NULL" queryout "' + @summaryNydFile + '" -c -Uusername -Ppassword'    
                    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
                        @cmdQueryout
                END    
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            EXEC dbo.spGetDatabaseErrorInfo
        END CATCH   
    END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

I cannot use the BCP utility while a transaction is open. I must commit the transaction and then use BCP.

Comment: I was facing the same issue; BCP execution never ended. then noticed the problem was related to the transaction. I searched and I found your problem to confirm my hypothese